# How to make webservice for an online marketing application

Tags: android

I am new to Android programming and I want to make an online marketing app, but I have no website as web service for send and receive data in database between server and client. What can I use instead of a website?

Can I use any free API for it? I searched API and checkout below links:

- https://moz.com/blog/apis-for-datadriven-marketers
- https://www.programmableweb.com/category/marketing/api

Comment: I know you're trying to avoid a website (maybe because you think it'll be hard or expensive to set up one), but you could definitely just set up a free Tumblr/WordPress/Google site and load it from a [WebView](https://github.com/QuaestioOrg/android-kotlin-webview) pretty easily and with no costs at all. I'm just stating that because it may be way easier than dealing with APIs or Firebase development environment.

Answer (score 1):

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start

Maybe you can use Firebase for data store and retrive in realtime: and it's free

- https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/?pli=1

You can create your own database and retrive and store date there.

- https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android

for referance its github example